# ORA-06550: row 1, column 7: PLS-00306: ORA-06550: wrong number or types of arguments

Tags: java, oracle, mybatis, ibatis

i'm trying to call a stored procedure with few parameter and one of them is a VARRAY of an OBJECT in Oracle DB. But i think the problem is with the parameters OUT. I'm using MyBatis.

This is the procedure:

```
procedure pr_log_admin(IN_nome_procedura in varchar2,
                            IN_id_utente in number,
                            IN_id_record in varchar2,
                            IN_nome_tabella in varchar2,
                            IN_altri_campi in V_ELENCO_CAMPI_MODIFICATI,
                            err_text out varchar2,
                            err_code out number)
```

This the types:

```
create or replace TYPE          "V_ELENCO_CAMPI_MODIFICATI"                                          as varray(200) of ty_campi_modificati;
```

```
create or replace TYPE          "TY_CAMPI_MODIFICATI"                                          AS OBJECT (
    nome_campo      varchar2(100),
    valore_old      varchar2(100),
    valore_new      varchar2(100)
);
```

Here the mapper:

```
<select id="log" statementType="CALLABLE"
        parameterType="com.ubiss.domain.logger.LoggedElement"
        resultMap="loggedResult">
        {call dynapp.pkg_log_admin.pr_log_admin(
        #{nomeProcedura, mode=IN, jdbcType=VARCHAR},
        #{idUser, mode=IN, jdbcType=NUMERIC},
        #{idRecord, mode=IN, jdbcType=VARCHAR},
        #{nomeTabella, mode=IN, jdbcType=VARCHAR},
        #{altriCampi, mode=IN, jdbcType=ARRAY},
        #{errText,jdbcType=VARCHAR, javaType=java.lang.String, mode=OUT},
        #{errCode,jdbcType=NUMERIC, javaType=java.lang.Long, mode=OUT}
        )}
    </select>

    <resultMap id="loggedResult"
        type="com.ubiss.domain.logger.LoggedElement">
        <id column="IN_nome_procedura" property="nomeProcedura" />
        <id column="IN_id_utente" property="idUtente" />
        <id column="IN_id_record" property="idRecord" />
        <id column="IN_nome_tabella" property="nomeTabella" />
        <id column="IN_altri_campi" property="altriCampi" typeHandler="com.ubiss.domain.logger.ElencoCampiTypeHandler" />
        <id column="err_text" property="errText" />
        <id column="err_code" property="errCode" />
    </resultMap>
```

Here Java classes:

```
public interface LoggerDao {
    
    public LoggedElement log(LoggedElement elementLogged);
}
```

```
package com.ubiss.domain.logger;

import com.ubiss.domain.BaseSpResult;

public class LoggedElement extends BaseSpResult{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    private String nomeProcedura;
    private Long idUser;
    private String idRecord;
    private String nomeTabella;
    private ElencoCampiModificati altriCampi;
    
    public LoggedElement() {}
    
    public LoggedElement(String nomeProcedura, Long idUser, String idRecord, String nomeTabella,
            ElencoCampiModificati altriCampi) {
        super();
        this.nomeProcedura = nomeProcedura;
        this.idUser = idUser;
        this.idRecord = idRecord;
        this.nomeTabella = nomeTabella;
        this.altriCampi = altriCampi;
    }
    public String getNomeProcedura() {
        return nomeProcedura;
    }
    public void setNomeProcedura(String nomeProcedura) {
        this.nomeProcedura = nomeProcedura;
    }
    public Long getIdUser() {
        return idUser;
    }
    public void setIdUser(Long idUser) {
        this.idUser = idUser;
    }
    public String getIdRecord() {
        return idRecord;
    }
    public void setIdRecord(String idRecord) {
        this.idRecord = idRecord;
    }
    public String getNomeTabella() {
        return nomeTabella;
    }
    public void setNomeTabella(String nomeTabella) {
        this.nomeTabella = nomeTabella;
    }
    public ElencoCampiModificati getAltriCampi() {
        return altriCampi;
    }
    public void setAltriCampi(ElencoCampiModificati altriCampi) {
        this.altriCampi = altriCampi;
    }
    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }
}
```

```
package com.ubiss.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class BaseSpResult implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected Long errCode;
    protected String errText;

    public Long getErrCode() {
        return errCode;
    }

    public void setErrCode(Long errCode) {
        this.errCode = errCode;
    }

    public String getErrText() {
        return errText;
    }

    public void setErrText(String errText) {
        this.errText = errText;
    }

    public boolean isOk() {
        return (errCode == null) || (errCode == 0);
    }

    /**
     * Builds an error description using errCode: errText Deprecated: Use
     * {@link buildDescription()} instead
     * 
     * @return
     */
    @Deprecated()
    public String buildErrorDescription() {
        String errMsg = "";
        if (!isOk()) {
            errMsg = errCode.toString();
            if (!"".equals(errText) && errText != null) {
                errMsg = errMsg + ": " + errText;
            }
        }
        return errMsg;
    }

    /**
     * Builds a return description message using errCode: errText. Note that errCode and errText will also carry success code and text. 
     * @return
     */
    public String buildDescription() {
        String errMsg = "";
        if (errCode != null) {
            errMsg = errCode.toString();
            if (!"".equals(errText) && errText != null) {
                errMsg = errMsg + ": " + errText;
            }
        }
        return errMsg;
    }

    public void cleanReturnCode() {
        errCode = null;
        errText = null;
    }

    public void buildGenericError() {
        errCode = -1L;
        errText = "Errore generico";
    }

    public String toStatusString() {
        return "{errCode: " + errCode + ", errText: " + errText + "}";
    }

}
```

```
package com.ubiss.domain.logger;

import java.sql.Array;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;

public class ElencoCampiModificati implements Array{
    private CampoModificato[] campiModificati;
    
    public ElencoCampiModificati() {}

    public ElencoCampiModificati(CampoModificato[] campiModificati) {
        this.campiModificati = campiModificati;
    }

    public CampoModificato[] getCampiModificati() {
        return campiModificati;
    }

    public void setCampiModificati(CampoModificato[] campiModificati) {
        this.campiModificati = campiModificati;
    }

    @Override
    public String getBaseTypeName() throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getBaseType() throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getArray() throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         return campiModificati == null ? null : Arrays.copyOf(campiModificati, campiModificati.length);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getArray(Map<String, Class<?>> map) throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.getArray();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getArray(long index, int count) throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return campiModificati == null ? null : Arrays.copyOfRange(campiModificati, (int)index, (int)index + count );
    }

    @Override
    public Object getArray(long index, int count, Map<String, Class<?>> map) throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.getArray(index, count);
    }

    @Override
    public ResultSet getResultSet() throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public ResultSet getResultSet(Map<String, Class<?>> map) throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public ResultSet getResultSet(long index, int count) throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public ResultSet getResultSet(long index, int count, Map<String, Class<?>> map) throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public void free() throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }
    
    
}
```

```
package com.ubiss.domain.logger;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.SQLData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.SQLInput;
import java.sql.SQLOutput;

public class CampoModificato implements SQLData, Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String nome_campo;
    private String valore_old;
    private String valore_new;
    
    public CampoModificato() {}
    
    public CampoModificato(String nome_campo, String valore_old, String valore_new) {
        this.nome_campo = nome_campo;
        this.valore_old = valore_old;
        this.valore_new = valore_new;
    }
    public String getNomeCampo() {
        return nome_campo;
    }
    public void setNomeCampo(String nome_campo) {
        this.nome_campo = nome_campo;
    }
    public String getValoreOld() {
        return valore_old;
    }
    public void setValoreOld(String valore_old) {
        this.valore_old = valore_old;
    }
    public String getValoreNew() {
        return valore_new;
    }
    public void setValoreNew(String valore_new) {
        this.valore_new = valore_new;
    }

    @Override
    public String getSQLTypeName() throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "TY_CAMPI_MODIFICATI";
    }

    @Override
    public void readSQL(SQLInput stream, String typeName) throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void writeSQL(SQLOutput stream) throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }
    
    
}
```

```
package com.ubiss.domain.logger;

import java.sql.Array;
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.apache.ibatis.type.JdbcType;
import org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeHandler;

import oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection;

public class ElencoCampiTypeHandler implements TypeHandler<ElencoCampiModificati>{

    @Override
    public void setParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i, ElencoCampiModificati parameter, JdbcType jdbcType)
            throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        Object[] values = Arrays.stream(parameter.getCampiModificati()).toArray();
        Array arr = ps.getConnection().unwrap(OracleConnection.class).createARRAY("V_ELENCO_CAMPI_MODIFICATI", values);
        ps.setArray(i, arr);
    }

    @Override
    public ElencoCampiModificati getResult(ResultSet rs, String columnName) throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public ElencoCampiModificati getResult(ResultSet rs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public ElencoCampiModificati getResult(CallableStatement cs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

This is the call:

```
String procedura = "director_man.PKG_ANAG_CLIENTI.pr_AnagCensisci ---> parameters: ";
        procedura.concat("doTrigger=" + res.getDoTrigger() + " - ");
        procedura.concat("doMigra=" + res.getDoMigra() + " - ");
        procedura.concat("doInit=" + res.getDoInit() + " - ");
        procedura.concat("doPulisci=" + res.getDoPulisci() + " - ");
        procedura.concat("ndgCoi=" + res.getNdgCoi());
        CampoModificato mod = new CampoModificato("","","");
        CampoModificato[] arr = new CampoModificato[] {mod};
        ElencoCampiModificati elenco = new ElencoCampiModificati(arr);
        LoggedElement logElement = new LoggedElement(procedura, Long.valueOf(1), "", "", elenco);
        loggerDao.log(logElement);
```

This is the error:

```
Caused by: Error : 6550, Position : 6, Sql = BEGIN dynapp.pkg_log_admin.pr_log_admin(
        :1 ,
        :2 ,
        :3 ,
        :4 ,
        :5 ,
        :6 ,
        :7 
        ); END;, OriginalSql = {call dynapp.pkg_log_admin.pr_log_admin(
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?
        )}, Error Msg = ORA-06550: riga 1, colonna 7:
```

I tried to check the names of the parameters and their order to not differ between code and db side

Comment: what is a [mcve]?

Comment: Emmanuele, folks can't take the time to read through and digest this much code. Work on your issue until you get it down to the smallest amount of code possible and then if you still need help share that.

Comment: @EmmanueleGuerriero This portable [project](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/tree/master/so-56834806) demonstrates what you are trying to achieve, I think. If not, please create a small project like that and share it on your GitHub repo so that we can reproduce the error on our end. And, like the experts say, try to minimize the number of objects/tables/columns/etc..